# Update Formik's state from a button onClick

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a Formik form and when I click a button I want to update the form's state.

```
function updateForm(){
  //Update a product in the form's state

}

<Button onClick={updateForm}>Update Product</>

<Formik
    initialValues={{ products: {} }}
>
   {({values}) = (
   )}
</Formik>
```

I tried to update the `initialValues` but that will reset any current changes in the form's state.

I could copy the Form's state into a local `setState` and loop that back into the `initialValues` but that feels overkill, as Formik does that already.

I thought `useFormik` might work, but the docs don't expand how this might work...?

Comment: You are correct. You can use the `useFormik` hook here. Your initial values will be passed to `useFormik` and it will return you an object like`{setValues, values, errors, ...}` then you can use `setValues` in your updateForm function.

Comment: Can I use `useFormik` with a Formik `Form` element, rather than a generic HTML `<form>`  element, as the Formik docs suggests? Feels like the docs are lacking some broader examples.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I didn't realise you are using Formik's Form component as well. If you want to continue using Form, instead of `useFormik`, you can use `useFormikContext` with `Formik` and it will give you the same values as `useFormik`. Check the example on the docs: https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormikContext

Comment: I tried calling `setValues` from my function, but its undefined. Does it need to be called from a hook (e.g. useEffect)?

Comment: Just to be clear, the <button> that triggers the onclick event isn't inside the <Formik> element itself...perhaps that's why I'm not seeing the Context...?

Comment: Yeah, correct. The `useFormikContext` will only within the `Formik`. So unfortunately you have to go with `useFormik` and you can't use `Form and Field` when using `useFormik`.

Comment: I tried adding a button within the <Formik> element but even that onClick event still finds an undefined useFormikContext()...?

Comment: Yeah it won't work. You have to call the useFormikContext inside a component that is rendered in Formik. If you check the docs exam, the AutoSubmitToken is rendered inside the Formik and it is using useFormikContext

Answer (score 0):

Given the helpful comments from @aditaya81070, I eventually landed on this solution...

I also had to refactor my solution a little, because I had two Forms on the page and in order to use `setFieldValue` I had to nest both `Form`s within the `<Formik>` element, so they could communicate easily (they can still have their own state separately). But don't nest them within themselves as that's not allowed.
So this is fine:

```
<Formik>
  <Form />
  <Form />
</Formik>
```

but this is not...

```
<Formik>
  <Form>
    <Form />
  </Form>
</Formik>
```

Then I just pass in the `setFieldValue` into the callback of the button...easy :)

```
function updateForm(setFieldValue){
  //Update a product in the form's state
  setFieldValue('product.price'), 1.50);
}

<Formik
    initialValues={{ products: {} }}
>
   {({values, setFieldValue, validateForm}) = (
      <button onClick={() => 
                 //This is the import bit, to get the context.
                 updateForm(setFieldValue)
      }>
         Update Product
      <button/>
   )}
</Formik>
```

Comment: Nice one. I totally forgot about this render prop pattern of the context.